# SLAB, out-of-process: I cannot view the events when running semantic logging as service

Tags: service, process, console, out-of-process, slab

I can save the logged events in the database (with custom database sink) when running the semantic logging as console, but I cannot do the same when running as service. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the account the service is running under has the proper permissions. When you run as console you are using your permissions
In my case (for testing only on my machine) I had the service log on as me.